# Написание 2 летний / 2-летний

Tags: числительные, раздельно-дефис, сложные-прилагательные

На сайте грамоты.ру под темой *Как записать существительное или прилагательное, начинающееся числом? Как правильно: 3-х мерный или 3-мерный?* приведены примеры: 2 симочный   двухсимочный, 2-симочный.
При этом источник их статьи недоступен. Правила 1956 года предполагают только словесное написание и написание через дефис. Кто-нибудь видел, где установлено написание цифры и слова *летний* через пробел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правила 1956 года предполагают только словесное написание и написание через дефис.

**Так правильно писать и сейчас.**

В ответе на вопрос [**№ 275863**](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=spravka) приведены такие примеры:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В «[**Письмовник**](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kogda-nuzhny-bukvennye-narashcheniya-posle-tsifr)»   же эти примеры скопировались некорректно: «2 симочный» с бездефисным написанием просто-напросто «убежал» (что видно и по запятым) из примеров с  неправильными написаниями в правильные:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Вот так вот нечеткий интерфейс может ввести людей в заблуждение!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:  **2-летний.**

Но лучше: **двулетнее** растение или **двухлетнее** растение (разный смысл!)

**[Грамота](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kogda-nuzhny-bukvennye-narashcheniya-posle-tsifr)**

Как записать существительное или прилагательное, начинающееся числом? Как правильно: **3-х мерный или 3-мерный?**
Корректное оформление: **трехмерный (предпочтительно), 3-мерный.**

```
Если в составе сложных существительных и прилагательных есть 
числительное, то его можно записать в словесной форме 
(прописью) или в словесно-цифровой форме (цифрой и 
присоединяемым дефисом существительным или прилагательным). 
При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенные 
наращения после числительных не пишутся.
```

Вероятно, в примере **ошибка**. Надо: ***двухсимочный, 2-симочный.*** Это следует из приведенного выше **правила.**

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже предположили, что примеры ошибочны. Нигде не нашли вариант написания через пробел.

Comment: Да, скорее всего. Написание слова без пробела  даже выглядит странно.